# Why does Obito only grab some people when he teleports them to the kamui dimension?

Tags: naruto

Take for example when he's fighting Danzos subordinates. He grabs onto one of them when he teleports them, but for the other he simply uses it at a range.

And if he can just always teleport people from a range, why was he always so insistent on grabbing his opponent? He could have just attempted to long-range kamui on Minato and Naruto instead of always trying to grab them.

Comment: His power is consisted of two parts, first to teleport others into or out of kamui dimention, two to be constantly in touch with kamui dimention and teleport himself and parts of his body there. I assume the second one takes less energy is more practical so he tries to touch the oponent to make him part of his own body and use the second power of his eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Tobi couldn't attack and defend at the same time with Kamui. 
His strategy was to allow his opponent to attack, but by using Kamui, the attack would fly straight through.

[image]
If Minato didn't have the teleportation, Tobi would have won.
Tobi's strategy is actually quite interesting, as he didn't use the kamui in the way that you thought that he would. I think that this is Obito's way of doing. He could use the Kamui in that way but chooses not to, because his strategy is more tactical.